# When passing multiple values for a field using ajax (jQuery): how do I avoid getting "fieldName[]" in request instead of "fieldName"?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to pass multiple values for a single field name to an ajax call:

```
<form>    
  <input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="MyValue1">
  <input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="MyValue2">
  <input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="More data...">
  <input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="More data...">
  <input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="More data...">
  <input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="More data...">
</form>
```

I cannot simply submit the form because the submission has to be done using ajax for reasons that are not relevant to this situation.

When I serialize this form data, I get the following:

```
formData: Object
  fieldName: Array[6]
    0: "MyValue1"
    1: "MyValue2"
    2: "More data..."
    3: "More data..."
    4: "More data..."
    5: "More data..."
    length: 6
```

So far, this looks good to me. Here is where I submit this to the server:

```
$.post("/MyHandler.axd", formData, function (data) {
       // etc.
});
```

On the server, code which I do not control does the following:

```
string[] values = request.Form.GetValues("fieldName");
```

At this point, `values` is null. However, if I do this:

```
string[] values = request.Form.GetValues("fieldName[]");
```

`values` has my array of length 6, with the correct data in it, etc.

I understand what is happening here, but I don't know why or how I can get around it. Is there a way for me to pull out `fieldName` instead of `fieldName[]` without submitting the form?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** After trying @raymondralibi's suggestions, I am now getting the following:

For the first suggestion (`getSerializeArray($(this).closest('form'))`), I get this:

```
formData: Object
  : undefined
  __proto__: Object
```

And for the second (`getSerializeArray2($(this).closest('form'))`), I get this:

```
formData: Array[1]
  0: Object
    : undefined
    __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Perhaps I am calling these incorrectly; any thoughts? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up getting this working, but I don't like how I did it:

Before the code that executes that calls `request.Form.GetValues("fieldName")`, I do the following:

```
    var entriesTable = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase).GetField("_entriesTable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form) as System.Collections.Hashtable;
    entriesTable.Add("fieldName", entriesTable["fieldName[]"]);
```

This copies the ArrayList to the correct key in the hash table, and everything works fine. Still, I would prefer to have this passed correctly from the client side, but for now this works.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
// $.serializeArray() return [{name:fieldname, value:MyValue1}, ...]
// this function will return {fieldname:MyValue1, ...}
var getSerializeArray = function($serialize_array){
  var obj = {};
  for(var i=0; i<$serialize_array.length; i++){
    obj[$serialize_array[i].name] = $serialize_array[i].value;
  }
  return obj;
};

// and this function will return [{fieldname:MyValue1}, {fieldname:MyValue2}, ...]
var getSerializeArray2 = function($serialize_array){  
  var arr = [];  
  for(var i=0; i<$serialize_array.length; i++){    
    arr[i] = {};
    arr[i][$serialize_array[i].name] = $serialize_array[i].value;  
  }  
  return arr;
};

// just call
getSerializeArray($('form').serializeArray());
getSerializeArray2($('form').serializeArray());
```

Comment: Thank you; sorry that I am only responding now, but other things have come up and I haven't had a chance to try this until now :-). However,  neither of these seem to be working. See my edit to the question.